# Use a Class to set parameters in another class - Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a Tkinter GUI and I want to add window sizing and positioning control in its separate class.
My structure is like so:

```
class MainApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.winsize= WinSize(container, 700, 500, 650, 450, True, True)
```

I want `WinSize` to set the geometry of the main application as well as handle
the `minsize`, `resizeable` in the WinSize class.

```
class WinSize:

    def __init__(self, container, width, height, minx, miny, sizeablex, sizeabley):
        self.container = container
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.minx = minx
        self.miny = miny
        self.sizeablex = sizeablex
        self.sizeabley = sizeabley
        self.ws = self.container.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.hs = self.container.winfo_screenheight()
        self.xpos = (self.ws / 2) - (self.width / 2)
        self.ypos = (self.hs / 2) - (self.height / 2)
```

I have been searching extensively and found no solution/guidance on how to get those implemented in the `WinSize` class for that particular instance and/or Frame.
I want to use the same class to be able to set size and other attributes to pop-up messages/Frames that will display other information.
The main GUI class is taken from @Bryan Oakley's famous example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7557028/7703610

How do I call the `geometry`, `minsize` and `resizeable` from Tk without having to inherit Tk again in my WinSize class and then apply it to that particular instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions. You can pass the window to `WinSize()` instead of the container, or you can use the [winfo_toplevel](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_toplevel-method) method to get the window for a particular widget.

The first solution would look like this:

```
class MainApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        ...
        self.winsize= WinSize(self, 700, 500, 650, 450, True, True)

class WinSize:

    def __init__(self, window, width, height, minx, miny, sizeablex, sizeabley):
        self.window = window
        ...
        self.window.geometry("%d%d+%d+%d" % (width, height, minx, miny))
        ...
```

The second solution requires no changes to the main app. Just add the following to `WinSize`:

```
class WinSize:
    def __init__(...):
        ...
        window = self.container.winfo_toplevel()
        self.window.geometry("%d%d+%d+%d" % (width, height, minx, miny))
```

Comment: Thank You @Bryan Oakley. Love how simple you make your solutions. Wish you did a set of video tutorials and teach the rest of us properly. Just a  quick question... is `self` passed into the `window` variable in the first example?